# Why wont my margins change? (CSS)

Tags: html, css

This is my first post and I am starting to experiment with Web Design, so I took a template from here:

http://www.onextrapixel.com/2013/06/24/creating-a-swipeable-side-menu-for-the-web/

I am trying to change the margins in CSS. I can't seem to get anywhere with it though no matter what I try. I have the code listed below.

EDIT: I am trying to get the p tags to move in 15px on the right. I also have the Jsfiddle link up. I also apologise for the images not loading up. The site is not live as I am doing it for a class in my High School.

EDIT 2: I got it working now.

https://jsfiddle.net/zbd9Lvph/

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    font-family: helvetica, Times;
    font-weight: 100;
}

.container {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transition:  left 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:  left 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition:  left 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition:  left 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition:  left 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.container.open-sidebar {
    left: 240px;
}

#sidebar {
    position: absolute;
    left: -240px;
    background: #007A00;
    width: 240px;
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#sidebar ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
#sidebar ul li {
    margin: 0;
}
#sidebar ul li a {
    padding: 15px 20px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 100;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #005500;
    -webkit-transition:  background 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:  background 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition:  background 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition:  background 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition:  background 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
#sidebar ul li:hover a {
    background: #00CC00;
}
.main-content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;    
}
.main-content .content{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-left: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin-right:15px;
}
.main-content .content h1{
    font-weight: 700;
}
.main-content .content p{
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 160%;
    margin-right:10px;
}
.main-content #sidebar-toggle {
    background: #007A00;
    border-radius: 3px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px 7px;
    float: left;
}
.main-content #sidebar-toggle .bar{
    display: block;
    width: 18px;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 1px;   
}
.main-content #sidebar-toggle .bar:last-child{
     margin-bottom: 0;   
}
.center{
    text-align: center;
}
#ctext{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 25px;
    right: 25px;
}
```

If anyone can help me it would be much appreciated. Still fairly new into the game so I am trying to figure stuff out.

Comment: Could you include your HTML too please? or create a fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Which margins are you trying to change? What's happening when you change them? What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: Can you please try to recreate the issue in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)? You have not given us enough information to solve the issue.

Comment: [Collapsing margins??](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing)

Comment: Advice - if you're just starting to learn, find something a little more minimal so you can understand what all the styles are doing, rather than some flashy touch navigation

Answer (score 0):

try adding `display: inline-block;` on those elements (that dont work)

Comment: Nothing changed when I tried that. I might try to change the padding on the div. That might work now that I think about it